# Most efficient way of building a list in a left fold?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

When building lists, I usually use a right fold, as that lets me use the right-associative `:` operator without affecting the order of the resulting list.  In a left fold, I could use `++`, but I understand that this will entail repeatedly copying the list while it is being produced, giving O(N^2) operations for an N-element list, which is generally unacceptable.

So, when I have to use a left fold (in my specific case this is because I'm using `foldlM` and the monadic actions produced *must* be performed in left-to-right order), is there any better way of reconciling this other than building the list in the fold using `:` and reversing the result?

Comment: In newer versions `Data.Foldable.foldl` is defined in terms of `foldr` to let the fuse with other operations. `reverse` should be one of these so you should end up with a pretty efficient version by just using `reverse $ foldl ...`.  My guess at least.

Comment: No, reverse does not take part in list fusion.

Answer (score 5):

> when I have to use a left fold (... because ... the monadic actions produced must be performed in left-to-right order)

Right fold can *lean so far right that it comes back left again*. For example, you can print (i.e. monadic action) each number and calculate partial sums of a list from *left to right* using a *right fold*:

```
fun :: [Int] -> IO [Int]
fun xs = foldr go (const $ return []) xs 0
    where go x f a = let a' = a + x in print x >> (a' :) <$> f a'
```

then:

```
\> fun [1..5]
1
2
3
4
5
[1,3,6,10,15]
```

note that the output list is built using `(a' :)` and the monadic action is performed left to right, even though it is a right fold.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention `foldlM`, likely this blog post of mine answers your question in depth:

[Constructing a list in a Monad](https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/620-Constructing_a_list_in_a_Monad)

The bottom line is: Use difference lists; i.e. in your left-fold, you accumulate a value of type `[a] -> [a]`, where you can append a value using `. (x:)` efficiently, and at the end you apply this function to `[]` to obtain your list.

Comment: Is a difference list better than accumulating a list and then reversing it?

Comment: Ah, I guess you found it so. I'm surprised; I've seen the reversal technique win (by a little) in other contexts. The whole situation is a bit unsatisfactory. I'd like to see a safe `IO` interleaving combinator that allows `IO` to produce a value lazily but does *not* allow lazy evaluation to drive `IO`. A sort of `lazyFixIO`.

Comment: I agree; a combinator for “here is an expression with an hole, I’ll fill the hole later” would be nice. But in any case it would be a mutable change to some closure, which the runtime/GC always penalizes.